# Blender 2.8 snap, knife tool does not work properly

Tags: snapping, knife-tool

Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684130/blender-2-8-snap-knife-tool-does-not-work-properly

1. Vertex extrusion to edge with snap enabled has gap (snap vertex to vertex is ok)

[image]

[image]

2. Knife tool does not work with vertices on face

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. I appreciate you have already asked your question on a different stackexchange site, but please include any relevant information (like screenshots) directly in this post too. The other link could disappear at some point and make this question unclear.

Comment: Have tried Ctrl+J - but nothing happened(before selected 2 vertices).

Comment: @vsw Oh, sorry, I meant just **J** to connect vertices across a face :) (my fingers remember, but my brain fails)

Comment: Only J said: could not connect vertices.